# Can X and Y Values be defined in Plotly using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-python

For example, I have the following

Scenario 1 -

```
x_names = ['John', 'Jill', 'Sandy']
y_ages = 8,11,10
Trace00 = dict(type = 'bar', x=[x_names], y= [y_ages])
plotly.offline.iplot([Trace00])
```

RESULT: For some reason the graph is not presented with any values

Scenario 2

```
Trace00= dict(type= 'bar', x= ['jack', 'jill', 'sandy'], y= [ 8,11,10])
plotly.offline.iplot([Trace00])
```

RESULT: Details are plotted succesfully.

Question: Can I define my x-values and y-values in the trace? Without having to type in each corresponding values?

Comment: change `x=[x_names], y= [y_ages]` to `x=x_names, y= y_ages`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work. As you are passing a list of lists to x and y, hence you are getting failed output.

```
x_names = ['John', 'Jill', 'Sandy']

y_ages = 8,11,10

Trace00 = dict(type = 'bar', x=x_names, y= y_ages)

plotly.offline.iplot([Trace00])
```